# Xcode Server - Build Service Error: The request timed out

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, osx-server, xcode-server

I've just started integrating towards my new OS X local server installation but I get an issue whenever I'm running an integration from Xcode on it. The tests seem to run but I get an error that the request times out. Also, the tests tab is completely empty. See image:

[image: Bot integration]

I'm running Xcode 6.4 and Server 4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. I figured it out. This is one of those issues that nobody can possibly have the same solution to but I will tell you anyway. My problem was that I had pointed localhost to my VM, i.e. another IP than 127.0.0.1. When I changed this back it worked great!